# if I have 1 M/Hs mined for me how does this translate into a bitcoin?

Tags: mining-profitability

I was offered 1 M/Hs per day for 37.00. What do I do with this in terms of turning it into a bitcoin. I am new to this and trying to make sense of all the mathematical gibberish

Comment: It doesn't. It's so little hashpower that you'll never earn a Bitcoin.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your renting a server in the cloud,you can use this server to mine for Bitcoin. Mining for Bitcoin means the server will use its fast computing power to decrypt a bunch of numbers constantly. When it does that the server is helping validate transaction for other people. For your investment in the equipment and time you get rewarded with Bitcoin. Over time it gets harder and harder to obtain Bitcoin because the encryption gets harder overtime. You need faster servers to combat this issue. This generates scarcity which in turn generates value for Bitcoin. You can mine alone or mine with many other people, but you have to share. You have to get mining software to start mining. This server you are renting might already have this setup. I hope this helps you understand. Cheers